# new 4th generation iPod touch doesn't have the app store

Tags: ipod-touch, restore

My brand new 4th generation iPod touch doesn't have the app store on it.

I think it's because I restored all the data from my old iPod touch and stored it on my new iPod, and my old one didn't have the app store.

I downloaded a software update on itunes to try and revert the restore, but after it downloaded, it said that it can't be un-restored, and I can't sync apps from my mac to my iPod for some reason.

Can somebody please tell me how to get the app store on my iPod and how to sync my apps from my mac onto my iPod? I would really appreciate it if somebody told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have all your media synced to iTunes on a Mac or PC? Then it's save to do a full restore of your iPod touch.

> 1. Disconnect the USB cable from the iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, but leave the other end of the cable connected to your computer's USB
>      port.
> 2. Turn off the device: Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button for a few seconds until the red slider appears, then slide the slider. Wait for
>      the device to turn off.  * If you cannot turn off the device using the
>      slider, press and hold the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons at the same
>      time. When the device turns off, release the Sleep/Wake and Home
>      buttons.
> 3. While pressing and holding the Home button, reconnect the USB cable to the device. The device should turn on.
> 4. Continue holding the Home button until you see the "Connect to iTunes" screen.
> 5. If necessary, open iTunes. You should see a "recovery mode" alert.
> 6. Use iTunes to restore the device.

also see: [official documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1808)

Comment: You will notice that these instructions do not always work, and that Apple employees will use the two button version of teh shut down http://codesweattears.blogspot.com/2011/12/putting-your-ipod-touch-into-recovery.html

Comment: i did exactly what you said to do, but a message on my mac came up saying "The iPod "iPod" could not be restored. This device isn't eligible for the requested build."

Comment: Maybe you need to update [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) on your computer because your iPod Touch is brand-new. You need at least iTunes 9.2 for an iPod Touch 4g. If that does not help, I suggest you open a new question or look [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/03/fix-this-device-isnt-eligible-for-the-requested-build-error-in-itunes-when-updating-ios/).

Answer (score 1):

You should do a factory reset of the iPod, and then configure again using iTunes.

I have posted an answer on how to do this [before here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34614/cant-connect-to-ipod-itunes-claims-ipod-touch-needs-passcode-entered/35627#35627)

1. Plug the iPod into iTunes
2. Hold the power and home button together until the screen goes black
3. Let go of the power button, keeping home pressed
4. after 10 seconds let go.
5. open iTunes and click restore iPod.
6. you have a blank iPod, and will need to sync again

Answer (score 1):

You could do a factory restore, where iTunes downloads a copy of the iPod Touch's latest stock "software" and installs it on to the iPod, which should get the App Store working. To perform a factory restore, plug in the iTouch, open iTunes, and right click on the iPod Touch tab > factory restore and follow from instructions from there

Comment: OP says they have already done this. 4th line